# Gray Box in Excel VBA Editor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office-for-mac

A gray rectangle appeared while I was editing when I pressed something I wasn't supposed to. Is anyone familiar with resetting the Excel VBA view or getting rid of this rectangle?

I'm working on a Mac.

**Edit:**

This occurred again when I did View -> Local Window.

[image]

Comment: I have never seen this in many years of VBA development using all sorts of hosts. I have never used VBA on a Mac. I'm afraid the bad news is that there are many things about MSOffice and VBA that don't work so well on a Mac. Try reinstalling or using office for Windows. You can use bootcamp or a VM to run Windows applications on a Mac.

Comment: Have you tried opening one of the script modules.  It doesn't appear you have anything open.

Comment: The *dark* gray rectangle looks like they could be a redraw artifact of the toolbars. Did you accidentally resize the toolbar panel (I don't know how it behaves on a Mac)? Does it stick if you minimize, resize, or move the window? The *light* (larger) gray rectangle would be the editor's empty client area, indicating no module is currently opened.

Comment: I think it may have been a redraw artifact like @MathieuGuindon said. Somehow my reopening and closing didn't work but a nice crash by Excel later on fixed it.

Comment: I'm curious –– is Excel Mac VBA known to be super buggy or is it just the Apple Architecture being difficult?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Half my work area was covered by the dark grey box. I tried to modify the toolbar, but VBA for Mac has no way to edit toolbars. After resigning myself to losing half my work space, I resized the editor larger, so I could see more of my code. Hahahaha, the resizing removed the dark grey area.

Answer (score 0):

In this pane:

[image]

... you have a couple `Modules`.
Double-click on an entry below it, that you have access to,
or create a new entry (right click on "Modules).